# ¿Es recomendable declarar e inicializar una variable dentro de un bucle?

Tags: c++

buenas. despues de resolver este [Ejercio](http://www.minidosis.org/#/actividades/Cpp.Ficheros.BCC.prob) con esta [Respuesta](http://cpp.sh/6orvp) me salto la duda si es una buena idea declarar e inicializar una variable dentro de un bucle.
esto lo realize con el fin de evitar escribir `i = 0`  **y**   `of = "email_.txt"` en el codigo.

nota: mi duda esta dirigida con un enfoque mas tecnico que visual.

Comment: Por favor, incluye **en la pregunta** el código sobre el que quieres preguntar; en el enlace que has compartido hay 60 líneas de código pero tu pregunta es sobre 3 de ellas. Lo ideal sería mostrar el código mínimo relevante a tu duda.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster tienes razon, pero mas de una vez he visto que cierran una pregunta por poner poco codigo, asi que no me "quice" arriesgar y coloque un enlace con el codigo completo.

Comment: Si te cierran una pregunta con [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) la pregunta está mal cerrada; de todas maneras si te cierran la pregunta ésta puede ser reabierta si se considera mal cerrada o si la editas para mejorarla.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo ideal es reducir el ámbito de las variables al máximo, de tal forma que su vida sea lo más corta posible. Esto, aunque no lo parezca, mejora la seguridad del código.

Es muy importante no reutilizar una variable para usos diferentes ya que ayuda a crear confusión.

Estos dos puntos tienen como conclusión que hay que evitar las variables estáticas salvo casos muy justificados.

La variable que usamos para recorrer un bucle normalmente debería ir declarada en el propio bucle. Así al finalizar el bucle la variable desaparecerá:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
  std::cout << i;
std::cout <<i; // Error. i no existe en este punto.
```

Si una función tiene dos o más bucles lo normal es repetir la operativa anterior para cada bucle.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, más de un bug he visto por reutilizar variables y olvidarse de reiniciarlas... Así que por lo general como dice eferion siempre que se pueda reduce el ámbito de las variables.

Comment: @FJSevilla ¿y se reinician las variables dandole valor a 0 o de otra forma?

Comment: @bassily cuando tú declaras una variable está contiene basura. Inicializarlo permite que la variable tenga un valor que no cause problemas, así que su valor inicial dependerá del uso que vaya a tener. El 0 suele ser el más habitual pero no el único. Si tienes, por ejemplo que iterar de 10 a 0 lo normal es inicializar la variable con el valor 10.

Comment: @bassily el concepto de reiniciar es un poco abstracto aqui, veamos, en el caso de un for en el que usas un entero como variable con reiniciar me refiero en realidad a darle el valor correcto antes de empezar un ciclo, imagina que tenemos `int i = 0; for (i=0; i<10; ++i)` Si ahora reutilizamos la variable i en otro for logicamente hay que tener cuidado porque i vale ahora 10, si necesitamos un ciclo que empieze en 20 y cuente hacia atras la 'reiniciamos' a 20, si necesitamos un ciclo que empieze en 0 la 'reiniciamos a 0'. Por esto digo que tal vez reiniciar no sea la palabra más apropiada.

Comment: A veces se comenten errores por hacer cosas como esta:`int i = 0; for (i; i<10; ++i){...} for (i; i<10; ++i){...}` y el segundo for nunca empieza porque i ya vale 10 del primer for. Es un ejemplo estúpido pero yo lo he visto, en códigos largos pueden pasar muchas cosas si no se es cuidadoso con las variables que se usan, por eso es recomendable reducir el ámbito al máximo, si uso la variable i para el for la declaro dentro del for y se evitan futuros problemas. Eso no quiere decir que declararla fuera y reutilizarla este mal, pero hace el código mas confuso y propenso a errores.

Comment: @FJSevilla ".... Por esto digo que tal vez reiniciar no sea la palabra más apropiada." reiniciar es la palabra apropiada.te pregunte porque mas de una ves me ha pasado que una palabra en español no re refiere a lo mismo al ingles. un ejemplo son los "arreglos" en C++.

Comment: Si tienes razón, lo que quería decir es que puede confundir a alguien, reiniciar no significa siempre poner el valor que tenia la variable cuando la iniciamos por primera vez, sino darle el valor apropiado antes de comenzar el nuevo ciclo. Con lo de 'arreglo' no puedo estar más de acuerdo, crea una confusión innecesaria. A veces traducimos palabras sin necesidad, de mala manera (un array es una colección, un conjunto, pero ¿un arreglo?) y otras veces usamos una palabra inglesa teniendo una en nuestro rico idioma que significa lo mismo (pero decir 'coach' suena mas guay que decir 'entrenador')

Answer (score 0):

Si lo puedes hacer siempre y cuando el alcance de esa variable esté dentro del bucle....no hay nada de malo en eso...

Comment: Hola Sergio, esto luce quizá más como comentario ya que la pregunta pide una aproximación más técnica. Te invito a poner un poco más de información :)